# While loop in Mathematica: multiple outputs

Tags: loops, random, while-loop, wolfram-mathematica

I have worked on a random number generator in Mathematica, suppressed by a number of conditions. Right now my code looks like this:

```
list = RandomSample[Range[36], 7];
f := If[1 <= Count[Select[list, # <= 12 &], _Integer] <= 2,
  If[Count[Select[list, # > 31 &], _Integer] >= 1,
   If[Count[Select[list, Divisible[#, {2, 7}] &], _Integer] <= 3, 
    Sort[list], False], False], False]
While[f == False,
  list = RandomSample[Range[36], 7];
  If[list == f, f]];
f
```

It is build up like this:

1. A random list of 7 integers of the interval 1-36 is made
2. f defines some conditions that have to be met: at least one and at most two elements in the range 1-12. At least one element greater than 31. At most 3 elements can be divisible be the integers in the range 2-7.
3. If the conditions are met, f equals the list, False otherwise.
4. Next thing is the "While" loop. If f is False, then a new list i generated, and this loop continues until f i no longer False.
5. The result stored in f is called.

The thing is now: this only produces one line of output. I am interested in getting multiple outputs, e.g. 5-10. I have tried to do it in some way with the Table command, but the thing is that nothing defines both the function f and the while loop at the same time. So, by running table on f, I only get the same result a lot of times.

Any input on how to proceed here?

Comment: As written, the last line in your while loop doesn't do anything as the while's output is suppressed due to the `;` after it. As the loop selects a list matching the condition you want, the `f` after the loop will then return the selected list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `f` references `list` as a free variable instead of as a parameter.  While this is not an insurmountable obstacle, it does make it awkward to package up this functionality so that it can be used in a `Table`.  Let's rework these definitions and apply some simplifications along the way.

First, let's tackle the test as to whether a sample is acceptable:

```
acceptableQ[sample_] :=
  MemberQ[sample, n_ /; n > 31] &&
  1 <= Count[sample, n_ /; n <= 12] <= 2 &&
  Count[sample, n_ /; divisible2to7[n]] <= 3

divisible2to7[n_] := MemberQ[Range[2, 7], d_ /; Divisible[n, d]]
```

The main simplification from the original is that the nested `If` statements have been flattened into an `And` condition.  The new definition also exploits the fact that `Count` can test list values without having to invoke a nested `Select`.  In addition, existence checks have been expressed using `MemberQ[...]`.  A helper function has been introduced to perform the divisibility check in an effort to reduce the visual complexity of the main test expression.  Note that the original divisibility check was incorrectly returning a list where a boolean value was expected.  The `_Integer` head tests were removed, but if they are deemed desirable they can be re-introduced by changing each `n_` to `n_Integer`.

Now we just need a way to generate samples in a loop until an acceptable one is found:

```
generateSample[] :=
  While[
    True
  , RandomSample[Range[36], 7] /.
      s_ :> If[acceptableQ[s], Return[Sort @ s]]
  ]
```

`generateSample[]` can now be used to generate a table of as many results as needed:

```
In[113]:= Table[generateSample[], {5}]

Out[113]= {{6, 13, 17, 19, 25, 29, 33}, {1, 11, 13, 15, 31, 35, 36},
           {1, 10, 17, 23, 25, 31, 32}, {1, 6, 17, 19, 22, 23, 33},
           {8, 17, 19, 23, 30, 31, 36}}
```

**Generalizing the Pattern**

The pattern embodied in `generateSample` could be parameterized to accept arbitrary generator and filter functions:

```
SetAttributes[generatorSelect, HoldFirst]
generatorSelect[generator_, predicate_] :=
  While[True, generator /. s_ :> If[predicate[s], Return[s]]]
```

The `generator` argument is kept in unevaluated form so that can be evaluated afresh on each pass through the loop.  This new function can be used thus:

```
In[114]:= Table[
            generatorSelect[RandomSample[Range[36], 7], acceptableQ] // Sort
          , {5}
          ]

Out[114]= {{9, 17, 19, 23, 27, 29, 32}, {8, 13, 17, 19, 22, 23, 35},
           {4, 17, 19, 21, 23, 29, 36}, {1, 8, 15, 19, 23, 31, 33},
           {1, 10, 17, 19, 24, 29, 36}}
```

The advantage of the new function is that it can be used with any generator and filter functions.  Here we generate tuples of three integers that sum to seven.

```
In[115]:= Table[
            generatorSelect[RandomInteger[7, 3], Total[#] == 7 &]
          , {5}
          ]

Out[115]= {{2, 3, 2}, {0, 5, 2}, {5, 0, 2}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 4}}
```

As a matter of style, some prefer to avoid defining functions with `Hold` attributes unless absolutely necessary.  `generatorSelect2` reflects that design choice:

```
generatorSelect2[generator_, predicate_] :=
  While[True, generator[] /. s_ :> If[predicate[s], Return[s]]]
```

The only difference between this and `generatorSelect` is that the first argument is now expected to evaluate to a function:

```
In[116]:= Table[
            generatorSelect2[RandomInteger[7, 3] &, Total[#] == 7 &]
          , {5}
          ]

Out[116]= {{5, 1, 1}, {3, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 6}, {3, 2, 2}, {4, 1, 2}}
```

Comment: Update: I simplified uses of `!FreeQ[...]` to use `MemberQ[...]` instead -- not sure what I was thinking the first time around.  Also, I corrected a typo that resulted in an incorrect divisibility test (`divisible2To7` -> `divisible2to7`, oh the hazards of untyped languages).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the third line in your definition of `f` is doing what you think it's doing. Consider for example

```
Divisible[20, {2, 7}]
```

which returns `{True, False}`, not either `True` or `False`. This means that 
`Select[list, Divisible[#, {2, 7}] &]` will always return an empty list and 
`Count[Select[list, Divisible[#, {2, 7}] &], _Integer]`
will always return `0`.

If I interpret the conditions for the lists correctly, you could instead use something like

```
Count[Select[list, Or @@ Divisible[#, Range[2, 7]] &], _Integer] <= 3
```

With this and Alexy's suggestion to use `Sow` and `Reap`, you could do something like

```
f[list_] := And[
  1 <= Count[Select[list, # <= 12 &], _Integer] <= 2, 
  Count[Select[list, # > 31 &], _Integer] >= 1, 
  Count[Select[list, Or @@ Divisible[#, Range[2, 7]] &], _Integer] <= 3]

Block[{n = 0, list},
  Reap[While[n < 5, list = Sort@RandomSample[Range[36], 7]; 
    If[f[list], n++; Sow[list]]]]][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: I agree completely on the condition considering the divisible command - I simply overlooked that! Thank youso much for the suggestion on using the Sow and Reap. Thought about these, but never got it working!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reap` and `Sow` for this:

```
n = 1; Last@Last@Reap@While[n < 4, Sow[n++]]

(*=> {1, 2, 3}*)
```

I recommend also to look at the [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhileList.html): it may be found very appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This works ok.  Note the use of SameQ (===) for comparing possibly mixed types, lists and booleans.  E.g. `{4, 7, 17, 22, 25, 27, 34} == False` does  not evaluate.

```
f := If[1 <= Count[Select[list, # <= 12 &], _Integer] <= 2, 
  If[Count[Select[list, # > 31 &], _Integer] >= 1, 
   If[Count[Select[list, Divisible[#, {2, 7}] &], _Integer] <= 3, 
    Sort[list], False], False], False]

g := (list = RandomSample[Range[36], 7];
  While[f === False, list = RandomSample[Range[36], 7];
   If[list === f, f]];
  f)

Table[g, {9}]
```